# CSS percentage value needs to be different on live server than on local

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 site, and I have a page wrapper `<div>` that fills up the page.

```
<div id="page-content">
    all the html in here.
</div>
```

Using CSS, I put a background image on that `div#page-content`

```
div#page-content {
    background-image: url('somelinktoimageurl');
    background-position: 120% 10%;
}
```

I have the same site on my local server with same settings as the live site. However, on the live site the `background-position` percentage value needs to be altered to have it on the same position as on my local site. Different percentage values between local and live sites are needed to put the image in the same position. I really don't know why this happens. This has happened to me once before but I just changed the value on the live site and lived with it. But this time I would like to know why that would happen.

Note: the live and local site viewed in the same browsers, Firefox and Chrome.

I am adding some screenshots below, 
My livesite screenshot with devtools open showing the position value

[image]

Same on local

[image]

As you can see the on the local the same value sits a lot higher on my local.

Comment: and which one is behaving correct, local or live ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif both are correct in a sense. Its not about correct or wrong. Its different percentage value for local and live for the same effect.

Comment: sorry but how a different server can affect the background position? I think this is rather a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @fcalderan That is the question.

Comment: yes but one should be a correct one, i mean if with the same values both behave different, it means that one behave is wrong.

Comment: by the way am sure it's something related to encoding and file type .. it's maybe related to white spacing or something like that. You may use Windows in local and Unix are used in server

Comment: Agreed with everyone here: it's important to find out why it occurs, rather than randomly altering things until it happens to look right. You're sure it's not a matter of 1) cached old versions of the stylesheet, 2) different zoom factors for different URLs etc? Also, I don't like the `120%` for a position, but that may just be a remnant of an attempt to get things right. Anyway, can you provide a link to the live site, and screenshots of both?

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for your response. I have added a screenshot of my local and live site.You can see the position the image is at is different for the same value. Our live site sits on a private IP so it wont be accessible from public and locals being local.

Comment: @MrLister To add 1) Cache does not happen to logged in users so we can rule that out. 2) I checked the zoom factor and it is not that as well.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding. I have another suspect though. Could be the text. The local has a lot of lorem ipsum and the live only has some text.

Comment: Oh, so the files are different after all.

Comment: Not exactlym the content is slightly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the lines of text. As I have percentage based position, it is calculated on the total height of the page. Since I had more Content/Lorem Ipsums on my local, the percentage would obviously differ than the  live which only had fewer content.